# Windows phone 8 page layout weblike

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8

I am an absolute begginer in xaml page design but I simply can't find a way to simulate webpage navigation

I have a **large** amount of text that I want to show, but I can't find a way to simulate 
weblike navigation (by that I mean large content that user can freely scroll left and right and up and down on content)

I tried to stretch grid outside of emulator size but its like scroll to content placed outside of standard screen size

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can properly use a [ScrollViewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) to display your content. From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/design/hh202907%28v=vs.105%29.aspx):

> A ScrollViewer control is a rectangular area whose contents can scroll
>   to reveal other user interface items, or the remainder of a body of
>   text that stretches longer or wider than a view port. Scroll
>   indicators fade in as the user pans or flicks and fade out after a
>   second at the end of the gesture, but the scroll indicators aren’t
>   user actionable.